Automation of joining groups in telegram channels giving FCFS links
This is my VioletMonkey script the problem I am facing is that it clicks invite link but after that nothing happens not logging in console
like after inviteLink.click() the console.log('Proceeding Further') isnt getting logged which means script isn't doing further interaction

// ==UserScript==
// @name         Telegram Invite Link Auto Clicker
// @namespace    Violentmonkey Scripts
// @version      1.0
// @description  Automatically click Telegram invite links when they are posted in a specific chat channel and join the group
// @author       Your Name
// @match        https://web.telegram.org/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    const TARGET_CHANNEL = 'https://web.telegram.org/k/#-2159974321';

    async function setupMutationObserver() {
        const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
            mutationsList.forEach(mutation => {
                mutation.addedNodes.forEach(node => {
                    if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.classList.contains('message')) {
                        processMessageContainer(node);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        const body = document.body;

        if (body) {
            observer.observe(body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
            console.log('Telegram Invite Link Auto Clicker started.');
        } else {
            console.error('Document body not found.');
        }
    }

    async function processMessageContainer(messageContainer) {
        const inviteLink = messageContainer.querySelector('.anchor-url');
        const channelLink = getChannelLink(messageContainer);

        if (inviteLink && channelLink === TARGET_CHANNEL) {
            console.log('New invite link detected in channel:', channelLink);
            console.log('Invite link detected:', inviteLink.href);
            inviteLink.click();
            console.log('Proceeding Further')
            waitForPopupAndClickJoinGroup();
        }
    }

    async function waitForPopupAndClickJoinGroup() {
        console.log('Waiting for popup to appear...');
        const popupElement = await waitForElement('.popup.popup-peer.popup-join-chat-invite.active');
        
        if (popupElement) {
            console.log('Popup element found. Clicking Join Group button...');
            const joinGroupButton = popupElement.querySelector('.popup-button.btn.primary.rp .i18n');
            if (joinGroupButton && joinGroupButton.textContent.trim() === 'Join Group') {
                console.log('Join Group button found. Clicking...');
                joinGroupButton.click();
            } else {
                console.log('Join Group button not found or does not contain expected text.');
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Popup element not found.');
        }
    }

    function getChannelLink(messageContainer) {
        const channelLinkElement = messageContainer.querySelector('.peer a');
        return channelLinkElement ? channelLinkElement.href : '';
    }

    async function waitForElement(selector, timeout = 10000) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const startTime = Date.now();
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                const element = document.querySelector(selector);
                if (element) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    resolve(element);
                } else if (Date.now() - startTime >= timeout) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    reject(new Error(`Timeout waiting for element with selector: ${selector}`));
                }
            }, 500);
        });
    }

    function delay(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        setupMutationObserver();
    });

})();


Expecting to automate the group joining by making script to execute further steps after invite link clicked

When the inviteLink is clicked in your processMessageContainer function, 'Proceeding Further' is logged immediately, followed by a call to waitForPopupAndClickJoinGroup().
However, the click action on inviteLink may not always result in an immediate popup or the expected behavior due to the asynchronous nature of web interactions.
To ensure proper sequencing, it is recommended to await the click action and then wait for the popup.
Here's a revised version of your script:
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Telegram Invite Link Auto Clicker
// @namespace    Violentmonkey Scripts
// @version      1.1
// @description  Automatically click Telegram invite links when they are posted in a specific chat channel and join the group
// @author       Your Name
// @match        https://web.telegram.org/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {'use strict';

    const TARGET_CHANNEL = 'https://web.telegram.org/k/#-2159974321';

    async function setupMutationObserver() {
        const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
            mutationsList.forEach(mutation => {
                mutation.addedNodes.forEach(node => {
                    if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.classList.contains('message')) {
                        processMessageContainer(node);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        const body = document.body;

        if (body) {
            observer.observe(body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
            console.log('Telegram Invite Link Auto Clicker started.');
        } else {
            console.error('Document body not found.');
        }
    }

    async function processMessageContainer(messageContainer) {
        const inviteLink = messageContainer.querySelector('.anchor-url');
        const channelLink = getChannelLink(messageContainer);

        if (inviteLink && channelLink === TARGET_CHANNEL) {
            console.log('New invite link detected in channel:', channelLink);
            console.log('Invite link detected:', inviteLink.href);

            try {
                inviteLink.click();
                console.log('Invite link clicked. Proceeding further...');
                
                // Adding a short delay to ensure the popup has time to appear
                await delay(2000);
                await waitForPopupAndClickJoinGroup();
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error processing invite link:', error);
            }
        }
    }

    async function waitForPopupAndClickJoinGroup() {
        console.log('Waiting for popup to appear...');
        try {
            const popupElement = await waitForElement('.popup.popup-peer.popup-join-chat-invite.active');
            
            if (popupElement) {
                console.log('Popup element found. Clicking Join Group button...');
                const joinGroupButton = popupElement.querySelector('.popup-button.btn.primary.rp .i18n');
                if (joinGroupButton && joinGroupButton.textContent.trim() === 'Join Group') {
                    console.log('Join Group button found. Clicking...');
                    joinGroupButton.click();
                } else {
                    console.log('Join Group button not found or does not contain expected text.');
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Popup element not found.');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error waiting for popup:', error);
        }
    }

    function getChannelLink(messageContainer) {
        const channelLinkElement = messageContainer.querySelector('.peer a');
        return channelLinkElement ? channelLinkElement.href : '';
    }

    async function waitForElement(selector, timeout = 10000) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const startTime = Date.now();
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                const element = document.querySelector(selector);
                if (element) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    resolve(element);
                } else if (Date.now() - startTime >= timeout) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    reject(new Error(`Timeout waiting for element with selector: ${selector}`));
                }
            }, 500);
        });
    }

    function delay(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        setupMutationObserver();
    });

})();


I modified but it didnt worked

then probably restarting ur device is the best idea.

but make sure u save ur codes

did restart + saved too can ya give me your modified code

i think this should work...

unless there is some issue with your computer.

Check that CSS selectors like.popup.popup-peer.popup-join-chat-invite.active,.popup-button.btn.primary.rp.i18n, and others match the elements in the Telegram web app.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
